# Using jquery.go.js to retrieve raw HTTP responses

Tags: javascript, jquery, phantomjs

I am quite new to Jquery, node.js, Phantom.js and JavaScript in general and having a few problems wrapping my head around all of it.

I'm working on a simple script using Jquery.go.js (https://github.com/travist/jquery.go.js) that should log me in to a site, then access a specific resource and parse the response (JSON) that it returns.

So far I managed to get the login working, but am really lost now for the second part.

What I have so far is based on https://github.com/travist/makemeasandwich.js

```
var async =   require('async'),
$ =       require('jquerygo'),
path =    require('path'),
fs =      require('fs');

// Add some default configs.
$.config.site = 'https://host.com';
$.config.addJQuery = false;

var login = function(done) {
  async.series([
    $.go(false, 'visit', '/login'),
    $.go(false, 'waitForElement', '#email'),
    debugCapture('login1'),
    $('#email').go('val', 'email@example.com'),
    $('#password').go('val', 'securepassword'),
    debugCapture('login2'),
    $("form").go('attr','id','validForm'),
    $('#validForm').go('submit'),
    sleep(3000),
    debugCapture('login3'),
    print('Successfully logged in.'),
    sleep(3000),
  ], done);
};

var viewJournalEntries = function(done){

  $.config.addJQuery = true;
  async.series([
    $.go(false, 'visit', '/api/journals/show/546'),
    $.getPage(function(page) {
      // Is this right, what do I need to do here??
    }),
    debugCapture('step2'),
    ],done);
}

var debugCapture = function(fileName) {
  // if (config.get('debug')) {
    return capture(fileName);
  // }
  return function(done) { done(); }
};

/**
 * Method to capture and ensure the screenshots directory exists.
 */
var capture = function(fileName) {
  // Return the async function.
  return function(done) {

    // The directory to store the screenshots.
    var dir = __dirname + '/screenshots-ls';

    // Check that the directory exists.
    fs.exists(dir, function(exists) {
      if (exists) {
        $.capture(dir + '/' + fileName + '.png', done);
      }
      else {
        fs.mkdir(dir, function(err) {
          if (err) return done(err);
          $.capture(dir + '/' + fileName + '.png', done);
        });
      }
    });
  }
}

/**
 * Helper to print something when it is executed.
 *
 * @param {type} text
 * @returns {unresolved}
 */
var print = function(text) {
  return function(done) {
    console.log(text);
    done();
  };
};

/**
 * Helper function to take a pause...
 *
 * @param {type} time
 * @returns {unresolved}
 */
var sleep = function(time) {
  return function(done) {
    setTimeout(done, time);
  };
};

async.series([
  login,
  viewJournalEntries,
], function() {
  $.close();
});
```

The login works like a charm and I can call the viewJournalEntries function which calls the url /api/journals/show/546 that returns a typical JSON string like this:

```
{"data":{"id":546,"user_id":1,[etc...]
```

The screen capture proofs that it works, but I am just not sure how to proceed to get the JSON into a variable that I can parse.

Any help/directions are appreciated.

Thanks,
Ben

Comment: Don't you just want `JSON.parse(...)` or am I missing something?

Comment: It should be something that simple, but how do I get the handle to the json? What do I put in between the two round brackets ()?